# Effects of 200R (199R) instead of 220R in this circuit

Tags: resistors, midi

I'm building a MIDI in circuit, and I found out my batch of 220R resistors are actually 199R... Can this cause problems/have negative effects for using in a MIDI In/Thru circuit ?

[image]

Comment: Are they 10% resistors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using 199 Ohm resistors in place of 220 will slightly increase the optocoupler LED current, but the current will still be well within spec.

The lower resistor value should have no effect on the circuit operation.

**Edit**
199 is not a standard resistor value - even for 0.25% resistors.  How did you determine that your resistors are 199 Ohms?

Comment: Thanks for the answer (sorry for my late reply). I measured them with a multimeter and they all were 199R (at least the first 5 I checked). But just in (future) case I bought a set of 220R 1% range resistors.